# Why is there is no procedure with the name `apoc.cypher.doit` registered for my database instance?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I've been following this guide on neo4j

```
:play https://guides.neo4j.com/wiki
```

But I get this error

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.cypher.doit` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

I've checked all over stackoverflow and tried all answers but none of them worked

I used the installer to download neo4j

My Apoc jar file is in the plugins folder (when I click on the plugins option it directs me its folder with the Apoc jar file in it)

This is my Apoc file:

```
apoc-3.5.0.4.jar
```

This below used to =plugins ,it works the same though

```
#dbms.directories.plugins=/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-10be0a2d-3b51-4fd1-a91c-0bbbd1bb087d/installation-3.5.6/plugins directory
```

I've even tried changing this

```
#dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*
```

to this

```
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.*
```

I checked if it was deprecated but I'm pretty sure it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with some queries in the guide. You should replace `apoc.cypher.doit` by `apoc.cypher.doIt` (procedure names are case sensitive).

FYI, I made a PR for this : https://github.com/jbarrasa/datasets/pull/1

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot bro!